# How to access Windows shared folders using emacs

Tags: linux, emacs, tramp

I am using Emacs on Linux and would want to know how to access my Windows shared folders from Emacs. 
I am able to perform this operation using nautilus (gnome file manager).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Windows shared folders are usually samba shares which can be accessed using tramp. You can find the relevant part in the tramp documentation [here](http://www.fifi.org/doc/tramp/tramp-emacs.html#External%20transfer%20methods) in the "smb -- smbclient" subsection. The correct syntax should be something along the lines of

```
/smb:USER%DOMAINNAME@HOST:/REMOTEPATH
```

Comment: can you provide information on how to obtain the domain name and host?

Comment: You need to open the "System Properties" dialog, which can be opened by right-clicking on the icon "Computer" in the windows explorer and selecting "Properties". In the "Computer Name" tab of the "System Properties" dialog you can find a field with the text "To rename this computer or change its domain..." and a button next to with the label "Change", click on it. The host is usually the computer name and the domain can be selected in the field below. The link I specified states that the domain name is optional, so you can try to leave it empty.